# What is the correct way to test Webhooks?

Tags: node.js, meteor, webhooks

I have a ReSTFul API in Meteor. I use hooks from Mandrill, Stripe, and other libraries to update a collection.

```
Router.route('/mandrill/message_rejected', { where: 'server' })
  .post(function () {
    var request = EJSON.parse(this.request.body.mandrill_events);

    var rejects = _.map(_.where(request, {
      event: 'reject'
    }, {
      return object.msg.email;
    });

    Meteor.users.update({
      emails: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "address": {
            $in: rejects
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      $set: { status: 'rejected' }
    });

    this.response.end();
  });
```

My question is; how can I automate tests for this? The request is supposed to come from Mandrill. Is there some way to test webhook messages in a consistent way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) (although you can use other testing frameworks as [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)).

I combine the tests with the [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) library that allows you to perform HTTP requests.

The next part does the trick: set up a log and store the received JSON from Mandril or other hooks that you receive and build a library (or fixture) of incoming responses.

Then you can build up the different cases that you need, for example:

- Removing an expected field
- Sending duplicates
- And so on

Making this method consistent requires that you spend time thinking about what hooks you expect to receive, reading the documentation to evaluate if a case you are thinking on is not possible and so on.

I'll recommend you to keep the log of received hooks to improve your tests over the time.